# A plane has the same cardinality as a half-plane: how to map all values in polar coordinates? Also needs verification/refuting of 2 alternative proofs

Tags: elementary-set-theory, cardinals

> Prove that a plane has the same cardinality as a half-plane.

1. I decide to find a bijection in polar coordinates. The plane consists of points $(r, \phi)$ such that  $r\in\mathbb{R}, \phi\in [0^{\circ}, 360^{\circ})$. ($)$ because we don't want same point on $OX$ to have two different representations.) By mapping $(r, \phi) \mapsto (r, \phi/2)$, we almost get the half-plane -- other than the left half of the dividing line.
   I tried quite a few things to circumvent this (mapping four arbitrary half-lines of the half-plane to the four half-lines of $OXY$ and constructing from there, for example), but nothing yielded a bijection.

**My Q1, is it possible to find a polar bijection from half-plane to whole plane? How?**

2. $(x, y) \mapsto (x, \frac{1}{2^y})$.
   That is, when we define half-plane as not including the separating line.
3. The third attempt seems valid to me, but not sure if rigourous enough. 
   [image: half-plane has the same cardinality as whole plane: proof in one picture]

**My Q2 and Q3 are, are the attempts 2 and 3 correct? If no, where? How can I improve them?**

Alternative proofs are also very welcome.

Thank you.

Comment: Remember that the polar coordinates of the origin are not unique.

Comment: To just show that cardinalities are the same, one usually wouldn’t construct a bijection explicitly, one would just show the existence of in injection (the inclusion map) and a subjection from the half plane to the plane. For the surjection just double the angle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As noted, the origin has no unique polar coordinates so we'll define a bijection from $\mathbb{R}^2 \setminus \{0,0\}$ to $\mathbb{R} \times (\mathbb{R} \setminus \{0\})$.

Basically you're looking for a bijection between $[0, \pi\rangle$ and $\left[0, \frac\pi2\right]$.

First construct a bijection $f : [0, \pi\rangle \to [0,\pi]$ with

$$f(x) = \begin{cases}
\frac1{n-1},  & \text{if $x = \frac1n$ for some $n \in \mathbb{N}, n \ge 2$} \\
\pi, & \text{if $x = 1$}\\
x, & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}$$

Then $\frac12 f : [0, \pi] \to \left[0, \frac\pi2\right]$ is a bijection.

Now define $$(r, \phi) \mapsto \left(r, \frac12f(\phi)\right)$$

and verify that this is a bijection between $\mathbb{R}^2 \setminus \{0,0\}$ and $\mathbb{R} \times (\mathbb{R} \setminus \{0\})$.

---

Your second approach is correct, but yes, it doesn't include the $x$-axis.

Your third approach is also correct, if you use rays of the form $\mathbb{R} \times [k, k+1\rangle$.